# spark-submit config through file

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

I am trying to deploy spark job by using `spark-submit` which has bunch of parameters like

`spark-submit --class Eventhub --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 1024m --executor-cores 4 --files app.conf spark-hdfs-assembly-1.0.jar --conf "app.conf"`

I was looking a way to put all these flags in file to pass to `spark-submit` to make my `spark-submit` command simple liek this

`spark-submit --class Eventhub --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --config-file my-app.cfg --files app.conf spark-hdfs-assembly-1.0.jar --conf "app.conf"`

anyone know if this is possible ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `--properties-file` which should include parameters with starting keyword `spark` like

```
spark.driver.memory 5g
spark.executor.memory 10g
```

And command should look like:

```
spark-submit --class Eventhub --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --properties-file <path-to-your-conf-file> --files app.conf spark-hdfs-assembly-1.0.jar --conf "app.conf"
```

Comment: I tried `spark-submit --class StreamingEventWriterDriver --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --properties-file properties.conf --files streaming.conf spark_streaming_2.11-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -conf "streaming.conf"` but got this error https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a18bc346841fe2012510ca30d0b3539c

Comment: If I run this `spark-submit --class StreamingEventWriterDriver --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 3072m --executor-cores 4 --files streaming.conf spark_streaming_2.11-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -conf "streaming.conf"` works fine

Comment: Error occurred due to incorrect hdfs config. The path for tar file  which should be loaded invalid

Comment: Is there way to correct it when using `--properties-file properties.conf`

Comment: What is content of yours properties.conf?

Comment: This what I have in properties.conf https://paste.fedoraproject.org/paste/PvirSfGpdPQGcOoK6smYeV5M1UNdIGYhyRLivL9gydE=

Comment: Check please  core-site.xml for hdfs property. It is obvious that it couldn't resolve hdfs configs.

Comment: But same command works with `--executor-memory 3072m --executor-cores 4` instead of `--properties-file properties.conf`. So I don't think hdfs config has an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting `--properties` as @FaigB mentioned, another way is to use `conf/spark-defaults.conf`. You can find where it resides by doing `find-spark-home` or locating and looking into `spark-env.sh`. Alternatively, you can define where this config is parked by setting the environment variable when or before you call `spark-submit`, e.g., `SPARK_CONF_DIR=/your_dir/ spark-submit ...`. If you are working with YARN, setting `SPARK_CONF_DIR` will not work. You can find out more here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties